# Implementing Iterable class on a Linked List in Dartlang?

Tags: linked-list, dart, iterable

I know that dart:collection library has a great Linked List implementation. Yet I am trying to implement a linked list myself as a part of a MOOC .

Here is my very simple Linked List implementation

```
import './node.dart';

class LinkedList {
  // root node of the list
  Node root = null;
  // the number of items on the list
  int _count = 0;

  // returns true if root is not set
  bool isEmpty(){
    return this.root == null;
  }

  // getter for the _count variable;
  get count{
    return this._count;
  }

  // push method to push a new item to the end of the list
  push(String content) {
    Node item = new Node(content);
    if (this.root == null) {
      this._count += 1;
      this.root = item;
    } else {
      Node iterator = root;
      while (iterator.next != null) {
        iterator = iterator.next;
      }
      this._count += 1;
      iterator.next = item;
    }
    return item;
  }
}
```

I would like to have it implement Iterable Class properties and methods like foreach and length . I read the docs for Iterable and IterableMixin class but I'm still struggling to understand how to use them with my LinkedList class since the docs give only example for using a Map as an Iterable .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `IterableBase` [docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-collection/IterableBase-class.html) and you should be good to go!